# How to avoid "TypeError: Cannot set property" error with jest and babel v7?

Tags: jestjs, babeljs

I have a project to be upgraded from babel v6 to babel v7. To make it work is not hard, but I met some problems in unit testing code.

For working code ***foo.js*** like below.

```
import foo from './bar';
export {foo};
```

When I try to mock it in unit testing code.

```
import * as Foo 'path/to/foo.js';
Foo.foo = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('whatever');
```

It fails with error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property foo of #<Object> which has only a getter
```

It turns out that babel v7 do transpilation different from v6. It compiles ***foo.js*** into:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "foo", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _bar.default;
  }
});
```

Since ***foo*** is defined as a getter-only property of ***exports***, it cannot manipulate the exported ***foo*** any more.

For the time being, I just change ***foo.js*** to avoid such transpilation. I'm wondering whether this is any babel config to disable such transpilation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In Babel 7, you can disable this behaviour by enabling ["loose" mode in `@babel/preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#loose). If you only want this behaviour for your test environment, you can further scope the configuration in your babelrc/babel.config.js.

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        production: {
            presets: [
                [
                    '@babel/preset-env',
                    { loose: false },
                ],
            ],
        },
        test: {
            presets: [
                [
                    '@babel/preset-env',
                    { loose: true },
                ],
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

See [loose transformation](https://2ality.com/2015/12/babel6-loose-mode.html).

Comment: I encountered issues replacing existing usages of jest.spyOn with jest.mock across a large codebase. However, this solution resolved the issues I was experiencing.

Comment: @noahnu I tried you solution. It didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion that Babel use to transpile properties differently than it does now. Properties that only define a getter are expected to throw a [`TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Getter_only) when using `"use strict"`, otherwise no error is given.

**Example Class**

```js
class TestClass
{
  constructor ()
  {
    this._propOne = "JUMP";
  }

  get propOne ()
  {
    return this._propOne;
  }

  set propOne (value)
  {
    this._propOne = value;
  }

  get propTwo ()
  {
    return "HOW HIGH";
  }
}

const testClass = new TestClass();

console.log(customer.propOne);
customer.propOne = "10 Feet!";
console.log(customer.propOne);
customer.propTwo = "20 Feet!";
```

**Babel 6.x Log**

```
> JUMP
> 10 Feet!
> HOW HIGH
> HOW HIGH
```

**Babel 7.x Log**

```
> JUMP
> 10 Feet!
> HOW HIGH
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property propTwo of #<TestCustomer> which has only a getter
```